# Ranma 1/2 fanfic where he runs away from Nerima and becomes a police officer. Had a running joke of a facehugger and/or Zergling

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, ranma-one-half

I honestly don't remember when I last read this, but I'm pretty sure it was over seven years ago and I think I first read it over ten years ago. The author had a number of "Ranma in a different setting" fics, I remember, including one where Ranma was in a post-apocalyptic landscape where he wielded a seemingly rusted-to-uselessness katana that was actually extremely sharp due to magic (he may have also been traveling with a minor priest underling who somehow gained access to a mystical orb that was incredibly sacred to his religion and gave him tremendous powers he barely understood). Anyhow, in this one, he's left Nerima behind (I think it was established that he did start there) and has become a police officer in another city. He still has insane physics-defying martial arts, but is also comfortable with mixing in handguns. The squad he works on is really quirky, although the only characters I distinctly remember was a female officer who had a violent split personality and a mad scientist type who I think was their medic, as well as coming up with custom equipment. Near the end of where I was reading, Ranma had wound up with a gun that borrowed bio-matter from him to shoot bullets of bone and blood (which didn't bother Ranma because of how quickly he healed) and the group had a genetically-modified creature that resembled a Starcraft zergling (I think it ate a few people before the group found it and decided to adopt it as a pet. It might have initially been introduced via a facehugger that kept killing random people off at chapter ends).

The general tenor of the series was fairly silly. A lot of people died, but no one important for the most part. I want to say that one or more chapters was devoted to them taking down a vampire nightclub with them more or less steamrolling that supernatural opposition between Ranma's martial-arts and general superior firepower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Guardian](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/720841/1/Guardian)" by Black Dragon6.

> Ranma leaves Nerima and joins a special police force. Special in that it's made up of psychos, fools, and nymphomaniacs all charged with protecting Tokyo from the supernatural and terrorist forces that plague its streets.

From the first chapter:

> Ranma Saotome, age 22, sighed forlornly as the train passed by, carrying its passengers to their destinations. He glanced at the red sign above and saw that his train was coming next, and briefly thought about leaving.
>
> He couldn't though. This was what he wanted.
>
> Or what he thought he wanted. He really didn't know anymore. Then again, it could've just been nostalgia from finally leaving his old life behind. No matter how painful or how much trouble it had been, it was all he had.
>
> His curse, his fiancees, his rivals, his legacy... he had thrown it all away for this, and it was too late to go back.
>
> Briefly dropping his bag to the cement floor, Ranma fingered the police I.D. in his pocket, and his mind wandered back to how it had come to this.

Found it with a search for *Ranma fanfic police zergling*, which got me a link to a chapter of "Millennium", which was a crossover with Sailor Moon.